# Error: libpulsecommon-4.0.so: No such file or directory

Tags: kde, 13.10

I get this error for kde apps after upgrading to 13.10:

```
$ dolphin
dolphin: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-4.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpulse0
```

then try again with logout/restart.

Comment: Raja, the package is wrong, is `libpulse0` from the [package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libpulsecommon-4.0.so).